# How to deploy a Yarn based Next.JS project on AWS Beanstalk?

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, yarnpkg

I'm trying to deploy my Next.JS frontend application, which is TypeScript based and uses Yarn package manager, on AWS Beanstalk, using the AWS console.

So far I have resolved all issues in the application and I'm able to generate a build of it, using `yarn build` command. The app also starts on using `yarn start`.

I have an environment in Beanstalk for the frontend app (Webserver tier). I just go to it and use upload and deploy option (thats the orange-colored top right button). On doing so, I get these following messages in the Events section-

```
INFO    Deploying new version to instance(s).
ERROR    Instance deployment failed to generate a 'Procfile' for Node.js. Provide one of these files: 'package.json', 'server.js', or 'app.js'. The deployment failed.
INFO    Instance deployment: You didn't include a 'package.json' file in your source bundle. The deployment didn't install a specific Node.js version.
ERROR   Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.
ERROR   \[Instance: i-08640cbf83d4e819c\] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Engine execution has encountered an error.
INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: \[Successful: 0, Failed: 1\].
ERROR   Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-08640cbf83d4e819c'. Aborting the operation.
ERROR   Failed to deploy application.
ERROR   During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate application version.
```

This is how my package.json looks like (partially), after adding the engines and node.js version in it, and modifying the start command(Note: I have tried the deployment process without these too, and not success).

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p $PORT",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
"engines": {
    "node": "18.0.0"
  }
```

My Next.js project folder structure

```
ProjectName

    .ebextensions
    .next
    - node_modules/
    - components/
    - pages/
    -- _app.tsx
    -- _document.tsx
    - public/
    - redux/
    - styles/
    .ebignore
    .gitignore
    - babel.config.json
    - firebase.ts
    - index.d.ts
    - next-env.d.ts
    - next.config.js
    - package.json
    - Procfile
    - README.md
    - tsconfig.json
    - yarn.lock
```

And ofcourse there are more files and folders in it. For simplicity, I've shown the ones I thought would be important.

Any help is much appreciated.

No logs are getting generated on the AWS CloudWatch for this enviroment. (An AWS expert says this is because the environment is unable to start the EC2 instance, and CloudWatch gets its logs from there.)